# My ui-router resolve don't return anything without errors

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have configure my MongoDb and API REST and when i tried to connect it with my Angular application i think it can't resolve.

I m learning MEAN application on this [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial).

This is my ui-router configuration.

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);
app.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
        postPromise: ['posts',function(posts){
          return posts.getAll();
        }]
      }
    })
    .state('posts',{
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: '/posts.html',
      controller: 'PostCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
  }
]);
```

And this one is my factory.

```
app.factory('posts', ['$http',function (){
    var o = {
      getAll: function(){
        return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data){
          angular.copy(data,o.posts);
        });
      }
    };
    return o;
  }]);
```

And this is the return of /posts

```
 curl http://localhost:3000/posts/
[{"_id":"564f63d0e1f4efce4e36d863","name":"test","link":"http://test.com","__v":1,"comments":["564f70adf3340cab52f9d117"],"upvotes":2}]
```

The result is a white page whitout error.
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you have here is with the $http service in your factory. You need to inject it in the function, like this:

```js
app.factory('posts', ['$http',function ($http){
    var o = {
      getAll: function(){
        return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data){
          angular.copy(data,o.posts);
        });
      }
    };
    return o;
  }]);
```

It the rest of the code is fine, it should work without any issues. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview) is one modified and simplified plunker that usses `$q` to return a promise instead of the `$http` since I don't have an http endpoint to call.

Answer (score 3):

Inject $http in your factory like below.

```
 app.factory('posts', ['$http',function ($http){ your code }])
```

Comment: uh Yes  you are right missing $http injection in service function

Answer (score 0):

One error I see is that you haven't returned a promise in your resolve. `getAll()` uses an async api and thus you will have to return a promise. So change

```
posts.getAll();
```

to

```
posts.getAll().then(function(data) {
    return data.data;
})
```

in your resolve. However, I am not sure if this will solve your problem completely.